# Sources not showing up in devtools even with css maps enabled

Tags: css, google-chrome, devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

tell me how to solve the problem. Sources not showing up in devtools even with css maps enabled

I tried changing the settings to dev tools

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the styles tab, opposite each rule should be the name of the file where this rule is written. Then it's easy to find where to make a style correction. But where the file names should be, I only have style.css.  How to return the names of the sources of the rules in the styles tab in devtools?